# I cant use matter js on codepen

Tags: javascript, codepen, matter.js

### CodePen matter js error

Hello, I am trying to use Matter JS on codepen, I firstly received the error that the variable Matter was not defined, I already fixed this but another error came.

Code Preview:

```
import * as Matter from:
"https://cdn.skypack.dev/matter-js@0.16.0";
let engine = Matter.engine.create();
let render = Matter.render.create({
  element: document.body,
  engine:engine
});
// and some more code...
```

Preview:
https://codepen.io/Eslare/pen/NWRQXpx

The Error:
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Matter.engine.create')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't import it in your JS section, just go to the settings and add it as external script.

[image]

Comment: Got same error on expo. I'm new to RN. Don't know what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

here a modified version of your pen: https://codepen.io/sessaidi/pen/abmeEbV, you need to add an external resource: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.14.2/matter.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you import it properly from [Skypack.dev](https://www.skypack.dev/)

```
import { default as Matter } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/matter-js@^0.17.1';
```

https://codepen.io/codepen0980/pen/YzNoxvd?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

You can use `importmap` on another Sandboxes instead of CodePan:

- PlayCode: https://playcode.io/1211140
- Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/CLvnZIBOHVQXzUSt

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body style="caret-color: transparent;">
    <canvas id="renderCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

    <!-- Since import maps are not yet supported by all browsers, it is
        necessary to add the polyfill es-module-shims.js
        Source: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation -->
    <script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>
    <script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
                "gl-matrix": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gl-matrix@3.4.3/+esm",
                "matter-js": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/matter-js@0.19.0/+esm"
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script type="module" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

js/main.js

```js
import { mat4, vec3 } from "gl-matrix";
import { default as Matter } from "matter-js";

console.log(`Matter.js version: ${Matter.version}`);
```